# How to parse XML using XPATH

Tags: android, xml, xpath

I want to scan following XML and fetch value of **id** based on condition name=task2 and value=efg.

```
<node1>
<node2>
    <node3>
        <id>ABC-123</id>
        <condition>
            <task name="task1" operation="and" value="abc" />
            <task name="task2" operation="and" value="efg" />
            <task name="task3" operation="and" value="hij" />
            <task name="task4" operation="or" value="klm" />
            <task name="task5" operation="and" value="nop" />
            <task name="task6" value="uvw" />
        </condition>
    </node3>
    <node3>
        <id>XYZ-987</id>
        <condition>
            <task name="task1" operation="and" value="cde" />
            <task name="task2" operation="and" value="abc" />
            <task name="task5" operation="and" value="nop" />
        </condition>
    </node3>
    <node3>
        <id>RST-567</id>
        <condition>
            <task name="task2" operation="and" value="efg" />
            <task name="task8" operation="and" value="jkl" />
            <task name="task9" operation="and" value="rst" />
            <task name="task10" value="xyz" />
        </condition>
    </node3>
</node2>
</node1>
```

I am able to scan and get result as count = 2, using

```
 String expression = "//node3/condition/task[@name='"+condition.getKey()+"' and @value='"+condition.getValue()+"']";
```

But not the value of **id** using following code

```
String expression = "//node3/condition/task[@name='"+condition.getKey()+"' and @value='"+condition.getValue()+"']/node3/id";
```

How to get values "ABC-123" and "RST-567" which would be the correct result?

Referring following blog and w3c links
https://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/12/24/android-xml-adventure-parsing-xml-using-xpath/

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_xpath.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_operators.asp

Comment: Please choose tags wisely. XPath is a subset of XQuery, and there is no XQuery support on android (without additional libraries, which you do not seem to use). I removed the XQuery tag due to being not related to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can nest predicates (expression in `[]`) to achieve that, for example :

```
//node3[condition/task[@name='task2' and @value='efg']]/id
```

Comment: Thanks :)
BTW, which is the best approach, yours or WERO's?
Need solution with faster processing.

Comment: @AbhinavTyagi har07's solution is very likely faster than wero's, because using the `following-sibling::` axis is probably more costly. It depends on the kinds of optimizations your XPath engine makes and usually,  the differences do not matter.

Answer (score 1):

You can select the ids and filter for the tasks with a following sibling condition:

```
/node1/node2/node3/id[following-sibling::condition/task[@name='task2' and @value='efg']]
```

To select only the text values use

```
/node1/node2/node3/id/text()[../following-sibling::condition/task[@name='task2' and @value='efg']]
```

Comment: Got the result from the first option but second option with text returned exception during evaluation.

Comment: something with String Reader...!

passing xml as string to input source

InputSource inputSrc = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));

XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

String result = (String)xpath.evaluate(expression, inputSrc, XPathConstants.STRING);

Comment: that seems to be another problem. Comments are not a good place to discuss exceptions, but you can always post another question.

Comment: I am fine with your first option :)