# How to parse and fetch exact result from XML using XPATH

Tags: android, xml, xpath

Using the following XML

```
<node1>
<node2>
    <node3>
        <id>ABC-123</id>
        <condition>
            <task name="task1" operation="and" value="abc" />
            <task name="task2" operation="and" value="efg" />
            <task name="task3" operation="and" value="hij" />
            <task name="task4" operation="or" value="klm" />
            <task name="task5" operation="and" value="nop" />
            <task name="task6" value="uvw" />
        </condition>
    </node3>
    <node3>
        <id>XYZ-987</id>
        <condition>
            <task name="task1" operation="and" value="abc" />
            <task name="task2" operation="and" value="efg" />
            <task name="task5" operation="and" value="nop" />
        </condition>
    </node3>
    <node3>
        <id>RST-567</id>
        <condition>
            <task name="task1" operation="and" value="abc" />
            <task name="task2" operation="and" value="efg" />
            <task name="task8" operation="and" value="jkl" />
            <task name="task9" operation="and" value="rst" />
            <task name="task10" value="xyz" />
        </condition>
    </node3>
    <node3>
        <id>PQR-345</id>
        <condition>
            <task name="task1" operation="and" value="ijk" />
            <task name="task2" operation="and" value="klm" />
            <task name="task8" operation="and" value="jkl" />
            <task name="task9" operation="and" value="rst" />
        </condition>
    </node3>
</node2>
</node1>
```

I want to get ID=XYZ-987 for condition name="task1", value="abc" AND name="task2", value="efg" AND name="task5", value="nop"

I am getting 2 results (ABC-123 and XYZ-987) instead of 1 (XYZ-987).
Using following XPATH expression

```
/node1/node2/node3[condition/task[@name='task1' and @value='abc'] and condition/task[@name='task2' and @value='efg'] and condition/task[@name='task5' and @value='nop']]/id
```

How can I filter these 2 results based on input condition size and get entry with exactly 3 conditions as stated above?

refer [XPATH executing complex queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35620660/xpath-executing-complex-queries/35620775#35620775) to develop expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer by appending  " and count(condition/task)=3" in the expression.

```
/node1/node2/node3[condition/task[@name='task1' and @value='abc'] and condition/task[@name='task2' and @value='efg'] and condition/task[@name='task5' and @value='nop']  and count(condition/task)=3]/id
```

Comment: did you mean `and count(condition/task)=3` ?

Comment: Yes, adding count I got the result

Comment: I mean there is no `event` element in the XML posted, but suddenly your answer has `count(condition/event)` in it. That can be confusing for future visitors, did you really mean it or is it a typo?