# XPATH parsing issue with complex data

Tags: android, xml, parsing, xpath

How can I fetch IDs with condition name="task1", value="abc" AND name="task2", value="efg" name="task5", value="nop"

Expected Output: ABC-123; XYZ-987
Actual Output: XYZ-987
Query: `/node1/node2/node3[condition/task[@name='task1' and @value='abc'] and condition/task[@name='task2' and @value='efg'] and condition/task[@name='task5' and @value='nop']  and count(condition/task)=3]/id`

Query Referred from [How to parse and fetch exact result from XML using XPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35770590/how-to-parse-and-fetch-exact-result-from-xml-using-xpath/35771147#35771147)

**Catch** if all the operation in tasks, other than satisfied tasks, are "OR" then that ID should also be considered as a satisfied condition. In the XML below, ABC-123, LMN-543 and XYZ-987 satisfy the condition but ABC-123 has all other operation="OR". So this should also be included in the result. By using count, I restrict to 3 tasks so ABC-123 is not included. Using count>3 will fetch ABC-123, LMN-543 and XYZ-9876.

**Need Output as ABC-123; XYZ-987**
using condition check on operation=or

Following is the XML used

```
<node1>
<node2>
    <node3>
        <id>ABC-123</id>
        <condition>
            <task name="task1" operation="and" value="abc" />
            <task name="task2" operation="and" value="efg" />
            <task name="task3" operation="or" value="hij" />
            <task name="task4" operation="or" value="klm" />
            <task name="task5" operation="or" value="nop" />
            <task name="task6" value="uvw" />
        </condition>
    </node3>
    <node3>
        <id>LMN-543</id>
        <condition>
            <task name="task1" operation="and" value="abc" />
            <task name="task2" operation="and" value="efg" />
            <task name="task3" operation="and" value="hij" />
            <task name="task4" operation="or" value="klm" />
            <task name="task5" operation="or" value="nop" />
            <task name="task6" value="uvw" />
        </condition>
    </node3>
    <node3>
        <id>XYZ-987</id>
        <condition>
            <task name="task1" operation="and" value="abc" />
            <task name="task2" operation="and" value="efg" />
            <task name="task5" operation="or" value="nop" />
        </condition>
    </node3>
    <node3>
        <id>RST-567</id>
        <condition>
            <task name="task1" operation="and" value="abc" />
            <task name="task2" operation="and" value="efg" />
            <task name="task8" operation="and" value="jkl" />
            <task name="task9" operation="and" value="rst" />
            <task name="task10" value="xyz" />
        </condition>
    </node3>
    <node3>
        <id>PQR-345</id>
        <condition>
            <task name="task1" operation="and" value="ijk" />
            <task name="task2" operation="and" value="klm" />
            <task name="task8" operation="and" value="jkl" />
            <task name="task9" operation="and" value="rst" />
        </condition>
    </node3>
</node2>
</node1>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to re-structure your conditions:

```
/node1/node2/node3[(condition/task/@name='task1' and condition/task/@value='abc') and (condition/task/@name='task2' and condition/task/@value='efg')  and (condition/task/@name='task5' and condition/task/@value='nop')]/id
```

Parentheses () are optional in this case but they improve readability.
note that as per the sample data you provided, LMN-543 also satisfies the query.

Returns

```
<id>ABC-123</id>
<id>LMN-543</id>
<id>XYZ-987</id>
```

I'm not very clear on your 'catch' condition, but based on what you say, it can be translated in each node having at most 2 operation="and" task.
This makes and additional

```
and (count(condition/task[@operation='and']) < 3)
```

so the xpath becomes

```
/node1/node2/node3[(condition/task/@name='task1' and condition/task/@value='abc') and (condition/task/@name='task2' and condition/task/@value='efg')  and (condition/task/@name='task5' and condition/task/@value='nop') and (count(condition/task[@operation='and']) < 3)]/id
```

which returns:

```
<id>ABC-123</id>
<id>XYZ-987</id>
```

Comment: Please see the question again. You have provided what I am already using. I need to get rid of LMN-543. Any solution for that?

Comment: edited answer to add additional constraint on operator

Answer (score 0):

`/node1/node2/node3[count(condition/task[not(@name='task1' and @value='abc') and not(@name='task2' and @value='efg') and @operation]) = count(condition/task[@operation='or'])]/id`

will return all ids where:

- the number of tasks that have an `@operation` attribute and aren't matched by the conditions `@name='task1' and @value='abc'` and `@name='task2' and @value='efg'`
- equals the number of tasks where `@operation = 'or'`

which is `ABC-123` and `XYZ-987`

Comment: I had to use XPATH query twice and then find the intersection of the two results to get to my desired results.
Above is small part of a large file, so there are more complex cases to get the correct output.